# Does there exist a graph $G$ such that every edge is contained in a unique Hamiltonian circuit, that is not a cycle graph?

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

Suppose $G$ is an (undirected, simple) finite graph. If $G$ is a cycle graph, then each edge of $G$ belongs to a unique Hamiltonian circuit. Does there exist a non-cycle graph $G$ with this property?

Comment: Or in other words: Is there a finite graph with exactly two Hamiltonian circuits, which are edge-disjoint?

Comment: Henning, I don't see why there needs to be exactly two hamiltonian circuits, I do see however why all the hamiltonian circuits need to be disjoint and how the graph needs to be a disjoint union of hamiltonian circuits.

Comment: Now that I think about it if such a graph doesn't exist for two it doesn't exist for more so it is equivalent in that sense

Comment: @Gamamal: Yes, that was my point.

Answer (score 1):

No such graph exists.

Every edge can be part of a Hamiltonian cycle, and the graph isn't a cycle.  From these, we can deduce that:

1. At least two Hamiltonian cycles exist.
2. All vertices have valence > 2.
3. All vertices have valence > 3.
4. All vertices have even valence.
5. The connectivity > 3.

For 2, we merely need to use the two Hamiltonian cycles.  They would necessarily need to overlap on the edges leading to the vertex of valence 2.

For 3, consider a vertex of valence 3, connected to vertices A, B, and C.  If the edges leading to A or B are removed, then a cycle still exists.  But that puts two different cycles going through the edge to C.

As a sidenote, that's what happens with the [Markström graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MarkstroemGraph.html).  If any edge is deleted, the Hamiltonian cycle is then unique.  But each edge supports two Hamiltonian cycles.

[image: 3 color Markstrom]

The [Meredith Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeredithGraph.html) is an example of a 4-regular 4-connected graph with zero Hamiltonian cycles.  After that, $K_5$ has 12 different Hamiltonian cycles, and that's the smallest possible number of Hamiltonian cycles for a 4-regular 4-connected Hamiltonian graph among graphs with <40 vertices.

Could the graph have valence 6?  If so, removing 2 edges could make the graph non-Hamiltonian.  Removing more edges would give a 5-connected 5-regular nonhamiltonian graph, which is impossible.

We're left with a 4-regular graph with more than 40 vertices. But it would also be a [uniquely 4-colorable graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniquely_colorable_graph), and those are known to be the [Apollonian networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_network) -- and these graphs have more than 2 Hamiltonian cycles.  So no such graph exists.

You'll need to settle for the [Markström graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MarkstroemGraph.html).